# What's the most idotomatic way of declaring two constructors with the same args?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

As an example lets say I have a class called `File`. Now file can be opened as binary or text. My constructor is currently `File(const char*filename)`. Let's suppose the implementation of open is completely different binary and text. How the heck do I construct this?

I thought about using a static function but I don't want to return a pointer. I could pass in a pointer but I rather not allow a class be constructed without actually initializing it.

I was thinking about having an enum or bool in the constructor but it feels 'wrong' to me (and the way I may do this). I could have a different class name for binary and text and have both inherit a base implementation (or the other implementation) even though the only difference is the constuctor.

What's the most idiomatic way of doing this in C++?

Comment: You could use a template parameter enum type and define types based on those arguments.

Comment: `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` both have binary and text modes. If you look at their documentation you can see how they handle it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two idiomatic ways are a factory function (nothing forces you to return a pointer), or tag dispatching (which is used in the standard library, for example in [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)).

```
// Factory functions
struct File {
    static File openText(char const *filename);
    static File openBinary(char const *filename);
};



// Tag dispatching
struct open_as_binary_t {} constexpr open_as_binary;
struct open_as_text_t {} constexpr open_as_text;

struct File {
    File(char const *filename, open_as_binary_t);
    File(char const *filename, open_as_text_t);
};
```

Comment: What does constexpr do here?!?

Comment: @EricStotch it's a shorthand syntax of `struct open_as_binary_t {}; constexpr open_as_binary_t open_as_binary;`. Just defining a ready-to-use object so that the call site looks like `File{"", open_as_binary}` rather than `File{"", open_as_binary_t{}}`.

Comment: @EricStotch: shorthand for `struct open_as_binary_t {};` followed by `constexpr open_as_binary_t open_as_binary;` to allow call like `File file(filename, open_as_binary)` instead of `File file(filename, open_as_binary_t{})`

Comment: But that could've been done without `constexpr` too , I think op is specifically referring to that.

Comment: @SombreroChicken It could've been `static` or `inline` instead. `constexpr` is just my go-to for tag objects :shrug:

Answer (score 10):

Add a flag

```
enum class open_mode
{
    binary,
    text
};

File(const char* filename, open_mode mode);
```

or use a tag

```
struct binary_tag { };
struct text_tag { };
File(const char* filename, binary_tag);
File(const char* filename, text_tag);
```

Comment: I like the tag!

Comment: Also worth to mention: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/ - its like the "tag" solution - you can have a interface like this: using BinaryFile = NamedType<const char*, struct BinaryFileTag>; using TextFile = NamedType<const char*, struct TextFileTag>; File(BinaryFile file) { ... } and File(TextFile file) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

> I could have a different class name for binary and text and have both
>   inherit a base implementation (or the other implementation) even
>   though the only difference is the constuctor.

Yes, in general, I can propose to use the polymorphism.
It is always clean, easy maintainable, extensible and understandable. Very flexible.
The best for creating something could be the factory design pattern.

Example:

```
class File{ protected: File(); ... }; // make constructor protected!
class BinFile : public File;
class TextFile : public File;
```

Then you could use it in the ordinary way:

```
File *f = new BinFile;
File *f = new TextFile;
```

Place all common stuff in class File
Implement any specific functionality per child class.

Then you could engage some factory method like:

```
File * OpenFile( String pathToFile, "TextFile" );
File * OpenFile( String pathToFile, "BinFile" );
```

In general, in this way, the code is very flexible.

Comment: As with the other answers, you should give a code example. Saying use Polymorphism is not a specific enough answer. Also, value semantics rule!

Comment: Once you have two separate classes, why would you need a factory at all?

Comment: @Quentin, you have to define classes, which will be instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

Why not even simpler:

```
File(const char *filename,const char *mode)
{
    fl=fopen(filename,mode);
    // 
}
```

And simply call with `myFile = File("log.txt","rt");`

Comment: Because it breaks the concept of "Interface should be easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly". This is very very easy to use incorrectly. What if i do `File("filename", "modeymodeymodey")`? Compiles and runtime error :( . But `File("filename", some_type_which_is_wrong)` will fail at compile time :).