# Overloading constructor with 2 same datatype members

Tags: c++, constructor-overloading

lets say i have a class with two std::string member and one int value, like:

```
class DataGroup final {
 public:
  explicit DataGroup (const std::vector<int>& groupNr,
                                   const std::string& group1,
                                   const std::string& group2)
      : groupNr(groupNr)
      , group1(group1)
      , group2(group2){};

  std::vector<int> groupNrs{};
  std::string group1{};
  std::string group2{};
};
```

Can i somehow have 2 overloaded constructors where one will initialize groupNr and group1, and other ctor initializes groupNr and group2 ? One of the strings not initialized in ctor call would be empty string then.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61887903/3233393).

Comment: Could you show an example of how you would use this, i.e. how do you want to use the different constructors?

Comment: You certainly can, but if you don't initialize any member variable explicitly, the compiler will generate default initialization for you. Relying on that may result to unexpected results.

Comment: @cigien it would be nice if i could call the constructor always with either one or the other string, i.e. 
  int a = 2;
 int b = 3;
  std::vector<DataGroup > dataGroupList{};
  dataGroupList.emplace_back(a, "Something for group1");
  dataGroupList.emplace_back(b, "Something for group2");

Comment: But the first argument to your constructor expects a `vector<int>`, not an `int`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, lets say both a and b are vectors then :)

Comment: Then both those calls are *identical*. How is the compiler supposed to know which parameter you mean to be default initialized?

Comment: Yes in this specific scenario that is true, does it make sense to have it like: DataGroup (const std::string& group1 = "",
                                   const std::vector<int>& groupNr,
const std::string& group2 = "") This way if string after vector<int> isn't given group2 will be empty e.g.

Comment: I would leave the constructor as is, and make calls like `DataGroup d(v, "", "something");` and `DataGroup d(v, "something", "");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several way to have expected behavior:

- Named constructor

  ```
  class DataGroup final {
  public:
      // ...
      static DataGroup Group1(const std::vector<int>& groupNr,
                        const std::string& group)
        { return DataGroup{groupNr, group, ""}; }
      static DataGroup Group2(const std::vector<int>& groupNr,
                        const std::string& group)
        { return DataGroup{groupNr, "", group}; }

      // ...
  };

  DataGroup d = DataGroup::Group2({1, 2}, "MyGroup");
  ```
- Tagged constructor

  ```
  struct group1{};
  struct group2{};
  class DataGroup final {
  public:
      // ...
      DataGroup(group1, const std::vector<int>& groupNr,
                        const std::string& group) : DataGroup{groupNr, group, ""} {}
      DataGroup(group2, const std::vector<int>& groupNr,
                        const std::string& group) : DataGroup{groupNr, "", group} {}

      // ...
  };

  DataGroup d{group2{}, {1, 2}, "MyGroup");
  ```
- named parameters (see [there](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/) for possible implementation)

  ```
  // ...
  DataGroup d{groupNr = {1, 2}, group2 = "MyGroup");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For overloading a function/constructor, they must have 2 distinct signatures. Since your intended types to be supplied are the same for both cases, you have to supply a 3rd parameter with a possibly default value for one of them. But again, watch for uninitialized local fields, since they will be auto-initialized by the compiler-generated code.

Comment: Are you saying I should just then initialize each string with "" if i want one of them to be empty e.g.?

Comment: Return type does not matter for overload resolution. And what's so bad about default initializers?

Comment: That's up to you what exactly to initialize, to me it would just be more explicit.

Comment: @churill they are hidden.

Comment: @churill yes sorry, return type is not counted in overloading.

Comment: I just mentioned this, because OP already has explicit initialization for each member. Also @Bodega a `std::string` is iniatialized to an emtpy string by default.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions here would be to simply have base class with "common" member

```
groupNr(groupNr)
```

and other two separate member have in each derived class, then you would initialize base member groupNr by calling constructor of base class when initializing derived one:

```
class DataGroup {
 public:
  explicit DataGroup (const std::vector<int>& groupNrs)
      : groupNrs(groupNr){};

  std::vector<int> groupNrs{};
};

class DataGroup1 : public DataGroup {
 public:
  explicit DataGroup1 (const std::vector<int>& groupNrs,
                                   const std::string& group1)
      : DataGroup(groupNrs)
      , group1(group1){};

  std::string group1{};
};

class DataGroup2 : public DataGroup {
 public:
  explicit DataGroup2 (const std::vector<int>& groupNrs,
                                   const std::string& group2)
      : DataGroup(groupNrs)
      , group2(group2){};

  std::string group2{};
};
```